# Adding custom styles to tailwind in react native expo app

Tags: react-native, expo, tailwind-css

I am using react-native-tailwind-classnames package and it has a json file where you can add your custom styles but everytime I add a new package the whole node modules folder is refreshed and i lose the styles i defined.
Is there a way to make something like a tailwind config file outside the node modules folder where i can add my custom styles

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is probable that you are not using the library in a right manner.

But just in case if you want to customise a "installed" package, there is this library - https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package - which will let you keep the changes in the installed package as if it was initially installed with the package. Also will let you share the same changes across the team using something like git.